# ajax user connexion

Tags: ajax, cordova

I'm trying to get userconnexion in Ajax (will be used in Phonegap application).

I've no javascript error but my ajax function is always with error status without details.

This is my form :

```
<form id="loginForm">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="user"/>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="pass"/>
                    </div>
                <input type="text" size="25" id="message" value="error" />
                <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sendButton"/>
                    </form>
```

This is my Js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#sendButton').click(function() {
             var user = $("#user").val();
             var pass = $("#pass").val();
             $.ajax({
                 url: "http://myurl.php",
                 type: "GET",
                 data: { username: user, password: pass },
                 success: function (html) {alert(html); },
                 error: function(){alert('false');}
              });
         });

    });
});
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['username'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];

$link = mysql_connect('dbhost', 'dblogin', 'dbpss');
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('dbname',$link); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email, mdp, id FROM auteur WHERE email = '$user'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if(md5($pass) == $row["mdp"]){
     echo $row["id"];
  } else {
     echo '';
  }
} 
?>
```

About my PHP I've try http://myurl.php?password=test&username=test and I get my ID, so I think this part works.

But when I try form with same value, I get a 'false', so an error...

I'm a newbie, someone can explain me my errors ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: are you sure you dont have errors in your queries?

Comment: yes I am, php works alone, so sql query is ok

Comment: so, your php alone works, which means the problem is on the way from form submit to phpcode, right?

Comment: maybe or in ajax request.
I've tried to put pass and login in static in PHP, result is the same.

Comment: wait i will try in a different way

Comment: and when I post form, I've good URL in console.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function submitme(){
         var user = $("#user").val();
         var pass = $("#pass").val();
         $.ajax({
             url: "http://myurl.php",
             type: "GET",
             data: { username: user, password: pass },

          }).done(function(answer){
             alert(answer + 'server is saying okay');
       });
    }
</script>
```

html:

```
    <form id="loginForm">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="user"/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="pass"/>
                </div>
            <input type="text" size="25" id="message" value="error" />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sendButton" onclick="submitme()"/>
    </form>
```

try this code.

Comment: this is an example url, it's not mine.

Comment: i know, but the ``false`` is saying that the answer from server is bad. can you see the error log in firebug

Comment: what is the message from server in console log in firebug?

Comment: When I post the form, I get my URL with good value in console, nothing more.

Comment: you can see, if you click on that 200 post in console, the header, parameters of query and answer from server, if you get ``false`` output from ajax, it must be something wrong in your php or on the way

Comment: ``if(md5($pass) == $row[1]){ echo $row[2];..`` try this code in yor php

Comment: I've false because I have an alert('false'); but in log I've HTTP/1.1 200 OK, all seems to be ok, just "origin" is on "null"

Comment: ``.success(function(answer){ .. }) .. `` instead?